# Tidyr solution to half-melted data

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to clean up some pump station data, which came from a plant operator manually entering in an excel-based log workbook values for DATE, and STOP/START volumes. What makes this tricky is that the three values were entered as repeating rows across multiple columns. Somewhat difficult to describe verbally (much less searching for if someone had a similar issue), hence calling it "half-melted". Here's what the dput of some of it looks like:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE", "STOP", 
"START", "DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE"), X2 = c(43466, 654896, 
654276, 43470, 657669, 656819, 43474, 660160, 659368, 43478), 
X3 = c("DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE", "STOP", "START", 
"DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE"), X4 = c(43467, 655298, 654896, 
43471, 658268, 657669, 43475, 660977, 660160, 43479), X5 = c("DATE", 
"STOP", "START", "DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE", "STOP", 
"START", "DATE"), X6 = c("43468", "655959", "655298", "43472", 
"658620", "658268", "43476", "661774", "660977", "43480"), 
X7 = c("DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE", "STOP", "START", 
"DATE", "STOP", "START", "DATE"), X8 = c("43469", "656819", 
"655959", "43473", "659368", "658620", "43477", "662673", 
"661774", "43481")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to clean this up into a timeseries with the three columns DATE, START, & STOP. Something that would look like this:

```
     Date  Start   Stop
1  43466 654276 654896
2  43470 656819 657669
3  43474 659368 660160
4  43478 662673 663168
5  43482 665148 665951
6  43486 667944 668537
7  43490 670950 671692
8  43494 673621 674418
9  43497 676090 676884
10 43501 678559 679399
```

I had never gotten a good feel for the gather and spread functions (still much prefer melt and dcast), but much to my delight I saw the updated functions pivot_longer and pivot_wider. I'm there's a tidy solution in any of those above functions, but I keep getting stuck by those functions wanting the current column names ("X1" to "X8") to be meaningful, but in fact they are arbitrary.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You've got more `DATE`s than `START`s and `STOP`s. Is some data missing?

Comment: Assuming you don't have data for the last row of dates, `df %>% slice(-10) %>% unclass() %>% split(rep(seq(length(.) / 2), each = 2)) %>% map(set_names, c('key', 'value')) %>% bind_rows() %>% mutate(i = rep(seq(n()/3), each = 3)) %>% spread(key, value) %>% select(-i)`

Comment: or `df %>% slice(-10) %>% gather(col, value, num_range('X', (1:4)*2)) %>% select(X1, value) %>% mutate(i = rep(seq(n()/3), each = 3)) %>% spread(X1, value) %>% select(-i)`

Comment: Oh, these were just the first 10 rows of this dataset, should have picked a multiple of three to make it cleaner! There are year's worth of observations :).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -

```
df2 <- as.matrix(df)
rbind(df2[,1:2], df2[,3:4], df2[,5:6], df2[,7:8]) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(X1 == "DATE")) %>% 
  spread(X1, X2, convert = T) %>% 
  arrange(DATE, START, STOP)

# A tibble: 16 x 4
      id  DATE  START   STOP
   <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
 1     1 43466 654276 654896
 2     5 43467 654896 655298
 3     9 43468 655298 655959
 4    13 43469 655959 656819
 5     2 43470 656819 657669
 6     6 43471 657669 658268
 7    10 43472 658268 658620
 8    14 43473 658620 659368
 9     3 43474 659368 660160
10     7 43475 660160 660977
11    11 43476 660977 661774
12    15 43477 661774 662673
13     4 43478     NA     NA
14     8 43479     NA     NA
15    12 43480     NA     NA
16    16 43481     NA     NA
```

---

Original data -

```
df
      X1     X2    X3     X4    X5     X6    X7     X8
1   DATE  43466  DATE  43467  DATE  43468  DATE  43469
2   STOP 654896  STOP 655298  STOP 655959  STOP 656819
3  START 654276 START 654896 START 655298 START 655959
4   DATE  43470  DATE  43471  DATE  43472  DATE  43473
5   STOP 657669  STOP 658268  STOP 658620  STOP 659368
6  START 656819 START 657669 START 658268 START 658620
7   DATE  43474  DATE  43475  DATE  43476  DATE  43477
8   STOP 660160  STOP 660977  STOP 661774  STOP 662673
9  START 659368 START 660160 START 660977 START 661774
10  DATE  43478  DATE  43479  DATE  43480  DATE  43481
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with a solution. I was trying to avoid pulling it apart and recombining with rbind, but looks like I'll have to resort to it after all!

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice `data.table` solution if you want, but it suppose that you have a start and stop for each date, which is not your case in your example. So I keep just the first 9 lines:

```
library(data.table)
df <- df[1:9]
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

Here is my three line trick:

```
melt_tot <- melt(df, measure.vars = c(paste0("X",which(1:8 %% 2 == 1)),paste0("X",which(1:8 %% 2 == 0))))
df2 <- data.table(type = melt_tot[1:(.N/2),value],
              value = melt_tot[-(1:(.N/2)),value],
              I = rep(1:(melt_tot[,.N]/(2*3)),each = 3) )
dcast(df2,I~type)

> dcast(df2,I~type)
     I  DATE  START   STOP
 1:  1 43466 654276 654896
 2:  2 43470 656819 657669
 3:  3 43474 659368 660160
 4:  4 43467 654896 655298
 5:  5 43471 657669 658268
 6:  6 43475 660160 660977
 7:  7 43468 655298 655959
 8:  8 43472 658268 658620
 9:  9 43476 660977 661774
10: 10 43469 655959 656819
11: 11 43473 658620 659368
12: 12 43477 661774 662673
```

The trick is to melt entirely the data on even and odd `X` columns

```
melt_tot <- melt(df, measure.vars = c(paste0("X",which(1:8 %% 2 == 1)),paste0("X",which(1:8 %% 2 == 0))))
```

I then split the value column in two : one with the value, the other with the type (i.e. start, stop or date), and create an index I spanning other the three types.

```
df2 <- data.table(type = melt_tot[1:(.N/2),value],
                  value = melt_tot[-(1:(.N/2)),value],
                  I = rep(1:(melt_tot[,.N]/(2*3)),each = 3) )

> df2
     type  value  I
 1:  DATE  43466  1
 2:  STOP 654896  1
 3: START 654276  1
 4:  DATE  43470  2
 5:  STOP 657669  2
 6: START 656819  2
```

I then just need to `dcast` it

```
dcast(df2,I~type)
```